# change HTML document default values

Tags: html, css

guys!

Is it possible to change a default value in HTML documentantion?

Example: If i set a color in CSS in HTML tag to green

```
html {
    color: green;
  }
```

and then i use the property inital in a class to back to inital property value

```
.initialClass {
    color: initial;
  }



<p class="initialClass">HI</p>
```

The "HI" color is gonna be black.

Is it possible to invert this? Is it possible to change the initial default value?

Comment: changing the invariants of a language is a bad idea. therefore uses css variables, they are precisely created for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. It was just a curiosity

Answer (score 1):

[`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) sets a value to its default *in the specification*, as in what CSS in general would define it to be, outside the context of whatever styling exists on the page.

It sounds like you may be looking for [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) instead?:

```css
html {
  color: green;
}

.initialClass {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p class="initialClass">HI</p>
```

Or perhaps [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset):

```css
html {
  color: green;
}

.initialClass {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<p class="initialClass">HI</p>
```